# How to make a function unaware of the allocator of its const argument?

Tags: c++, templates, allocator

I have a class template that supports different allocators for its member:

```
template<typename Alloc>
class Foo
{
    std::vector<int, Alloc<int>> data;
    // other members ...
};
```

Consider a function `func` that accepts a `const Foo&`. As the allocator is a part of `Foo`'s type, I need to declare it as a template as well:

```
template<typename Alloc>
void func(const Foo<Alloc>& foo);
```

In my understanding, when only looking at a `const Foo&` the allocator does not matter and therefore all instantiations of `func` would be identical. Besides code bloat, this introduces unwanted dependencies.

- Is there a way to make `func` unaware of the allocator?
- Would it be safe to settle for one allocator (e.g. `std::allocator`) in the function (which then no longer needs to be a template) and upon calling it do a `reinterpret_cast` from `Foo<MyCostumAllocator<int>>` to `Foo<std::allocator<int>>`?

I know of `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator` which does not suffer from this problem (as long as you only use pmr allocators), but this is not an option for me.

Comment: *Would it be safe...* - No!

Comment: "the allocator does not matter and therefore all instantiations of func would be identical. " that is incorrect, in C++ the individual specializations can be completely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you see with `func` is secondary. Different instantiations of `Foo` are completely different distinct types. Hence, also different instantiations of `func` must be different functions.

However, if the interface of `Foo` does not depend on the allocator, you can add a allocator unaware base class:

```
 struct Foo_base {
      // virtual interface
 };

 template <typename Alloc>
 struct Foo : Foo_base {
     std::vector<int, Alloc<int>> data;
 };

 void func(const Foo_base& foo);
```